# Redirect a 404 to another page and capturing the page with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, url-rewriting

Alright, what I'm wanting to do is create a .htaccess that will redirect any 404 error to another page while capturing the path/file attempted to be accessed.

So, if they are trying to access

```
www.mydomain.com/xxx
```

I want it to be redirected to

```
www.mydomain.com/error.php?e=xxx.
```

I've never been overly good at writing .htaccess files so any help someone could provide would be WONDERFUL.

I would need this to work sitewide.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# rewrite to error.php with a query parameter
RewriteRule .+ error.php?e=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to emulate what `ErrorDocument` does out of the box :-)

Comment: Do you seriously believe that I am not aware of `ErrorDocument`? :) Reason why I didn't use `ErrorDocument` because OP wanted 404 URI in a GET parameter.

Comment: Where does the OP say he wants that in a GET parameter? The intro tells "capturing the path/file attempted to be accessed". Yes, he did try to capture it using GET, it doesn't mean that should be encouraged using a very complex solution.

Comment: Please read it again: `I want it to be redirected to

www.mydomain.com/error.php?e=xxx.`

Comment: My point is, think out of the box and teach the OP a better method to do it. Yes, passing it as GET is what you would first think of, but it doesn't have to be the final answer.

Comment: It's not my assumption, this is exactly what OP asked for. Let's leave it to OP to chose whatever suits him.

Comment: Oh so the OP wants to do it in a complex way and you encourage him to do so. Even worse :-D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a RewriteRule to achieve this.
Just use the `ErrorDocument` directive.

It will serve the page you reference but will NOT redirect to it.
If your `ErrorDocument` page is a php script, you can then access `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to know what the not found resource was.

So, basically, you just need this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

And in `error.php`:

```
$notFound = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Or whatever variable you want to store that URI in.

The good thing is, since the user is not redirected to the page, a simple typo is easy to correct to go to the right page, whereas redirecting would force the user to type the whole URL again (also, he/she wouldn't be able to see what he/she tried to access).

From an analytics point of view, it's still a 404 without any extra code.
Redirecting to an error page would force you to add an extra 404 header to it (so robots don't index your error page, among other things).

In `error.php`, make sure all your asset paths are absolute, as it might be delivered from `http://www.example.com/xxx/yyy` and will look for relative assets from `/xxx/` (this path might not exist). So, even tho `error.php` is located in your root folder, using `src="img/404.png"` will not work as soon as the 404 has a folder in its URI. You have to use `src="/img/404.png"`.